# Compress and RESCALE uploaded image

Tags: php, image

I have a function that uploads files up to 8MB but now I also want to compress or at least rescale larger images, so my output image won't be any bigger than 100-200 KB and 1000x1000px resolution. How can I implement compress and rescale (proportional) in my function?

```
function uploadFile($file, $file_restrictions = '', $user_id, $sub_folder = '') {
    global $path_app;
    $new_file_name    = generateRandomString(20);

    if($sub_folder != '') {
        if(!file_exists('media/'.$user_id.'/'.$sub_folder.'/')) {
            mkdir('media/'.$user_id.'/'.$sub_folder, 0777);
        }
        $sub_folder = $sub_folder.'/';
    }
    else {
        $sub_folder = '';
    }

    $uploadDir  = 'media/'.$user_id.'/'.$sub_folder;
    $uploadDirO = 'media/'.$user_id.'/'.$sub_folder;
    $finalDir   = $path_app.'/media/'.$user_id.'/'.$sub_folder;

    $fileExt    = explode(".", basename($file['name']));
    $uploadExt  = $fileExt[count($fileExt) - 1];
    $uploadName = $new_file_name.'_cache.'.$uploadExt;
    $uploadDir  = $uploadDir.$uploadName;

    $restriction_ok = true;
    if(!empty($file_restrictions)) {
        if(strpos($file_restrictions, $uploadExt) === false) {
            $restriction_ok = false;
        }
    }
    if($restriction_ok == false) {
        return '';
    }
    else {
        if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $uploadDir)) {
            $image_info     = getimagesize($uploadDir);
            $image_width    = $image_info[0];
            $image_height   = $image_info[1];

            if($file['size'] > 8000000) {
                unlink($uploadDir);
                return '';
            }
            else {
                $finalUploadName    = $new_file_name.'.'.$uploadExt;
                rename($uploadDirO.$uploadName, $uploadDirO.$finalUploadName);

                return $finalDir.$finalUploadName;
            }
        }
        else {
            return '';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the rescaling I use a function like this:

```
function dimensions($width,$height,$maxWidth,$maxHeight)
// given maximum dimensions this tries to fill that as best as possible
{
  // get new sizes
  if ($width > $maxWidth) { 
    $height = Round($maxWidth*$height/$width);  
    $width  = $maxWidth;  
  }
  if ($height > $maxHeight) { 
    $width  = Round($maxHeight*$width/$height); 
    $height = $maxHeight; 
  }
  // return array with new size
  return array('width' => $width,'height' => $height);
}
```

The compression is done by a PHP function:

```
  // set limits
  $maxWidth  = 1000;
  $maxHeight = 1000;
  // read source
  $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($originalImageFile);
  // get the possible dimensions of destination and extract
  $dims = dimensions(imagesx($source),imagesy($source),$maxWidth,$maxHeight);
  // prepare destination
  $dest = imagecreatetruecolor($dims['width'],$dims['height']);
  // copy in high-quality
  imagecopyresampled($dest,$source,0,0,0,0,
                     $width,$height,imagesx($source),imagesy($source));
  // save file
  imagejpeg($dest,$destinationImageFile,85);
  // clear both copies from memory
  imagedestroy($source);
  imagedestroy($dest);
```

You will have to supply `$originalImageFile` and `$destinationImageFile`. This stuff comes from a class I use, so I edited it quite a lot, but the basic functionality is there. I left out any error checking, so you still need to add that. Note that the `85` in `imagejpeg()` denotes the amount of compression.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a simple one line solution through [imagemagic library](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) the command will like this

```
$image="path to image";
$res="option to resize"; i.e 25% small , 50% small or anything else
exec("convert ".$image." -resize ".$res." ".$image);
```

with this you can **rotate** **resize** and many other image customization

Comment: Good solution, but I only have web server, no root or vroot - but still thanks!

Comment: ok no problem . you have found your answer , thats matter . it can help to some other person

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [imagecopyresampled()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php), There is also a example that how to implement it, For compression take a look on [imagejpeg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) the third parameter helps to set quality of the image, **100 means (best quality, biggest file)** and if you skip the last option then default quality is 75 which is good and compress it.